# Santa Cruz but idk which model and year, please!

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, downhill, framebuilding

[image]

Hey can someone please tell me the model and year of this Santa Cruz frame I just bought... thanks!

Comment: It looks very similar to SantaCruz Superlight 2004. But that is only the front half of a frame It's missing the rear triangle. You'd need another donor frame to complete a bike.(And also a compatible rear shock).

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I appreciate it.

Comment: This looks again like one of the cases where asking the seller before buying would be the best option. It might also be interesting to know how they ended up having the frame without shock and swing arm but with bottom bracket and right crank still installed.

Comment: Why do you think it's worth knowing the year?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a 2004 model but it could be 2005 model for more information ask the dealer